# Jira OnDemand and ReST API output sorting

Tags: rest, api, jira, ondemand

First off, I am very new to ReST and have been googling for the past week trying to learn more about it. In particular I am trying to get information from various sources and compare them. The main source I need to grab from is Jira OnDemand. Currently I am just trying to grab the groups in the system using

```
http://<mycompany>.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/groups/picker?maxResults=10000
```

Which worked fine when I put it into my URL bar, and it output a massive list of information.

My questions are...

1. Is there a good program like NotePad++ that would let me write and run some of these scrips with basic help
2. If there is not, is there a way to have the information output from the line above to be better displayed? Like in a table or some way?

Comment: Have a look at Postman in chrome app store.

Comment: I will do that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ will work fine with this. Use your REST URL as the "Filename" in the Open Dialog. The results will show up in Notepad++. You can download the JSTool plugin to format the results to make them easier to see, using its JSFormat menu option.